# Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint SQlServer

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

[image]

[image]

```
string query = "Update Completed_orders set service=N'" + comboBox1.SelectedValue + "',kolvo=N'" + kol.Text + "',note=N'" + not.Text + "' where orders='" + form3.ordersgrid.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString() + "' ";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, dataBase.getConnection());
dataBase.openConnection();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
dataBase.closeConnection();
form3.serviceklient();
MessageBox.Show("Изменена");
this.Hide();
```

Вот ошибка:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: "Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__tmp_ms_x__1A00DC411E67C062'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Completed_orders'. The duplicate key value is (23, 1). The statement has been terminated."

Ругается на UPDATE
Новый код:

```
 string query = "Update Completed_orders set service=N'" + comboBox1.SelectedValue + "',kolvo=N'" + kol.Text + "',note=N'" + not.Text + "' where orders='" + form3.ordersgrid.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString() + "' and service='" + form3.ordersgrid.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString() + "' ";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, dataBase.getConnection());
        dataBase.openConnection();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        dataBase.closeConnection();
        form3.serviceklient();
        MessageBox.Show("Изменена");
        this.Hide();
```

Comment: Колонка `service` - ключ. Не надо её обновлять. / А вот в условии `where`, насколько я понимаю, должно быть и `orders`, и `service`.

Comment: смотрите Александр оно ругается из-за то что первичный ключ orders повторяется

Comment: И? От нас вы что хотите? / Повторяю: колонка `service` - ключ! Так она обозначена на схеме таблицы `Completed_orders`. Не обновляйте её!

Comment: а счас оно меняет везде в двух заказах

Comment: Кто "оно"? Если вы что-то поменяли в коде, покажите это нам: отредактируйте вопрос, добавив изменённый код.

Comment: добавил измененный код

Comment: я просто убрал service='"combobxo'"

Comment: Верните старый код как был. И ниже добавьте новый. Чтобы можно было проследить за ходом обсуждения проблемы.

Comment: **Повторяю**: в условии `where` должно быть и `orders`, и `service`.

Comment: типо такого where orders='" + form3.ordersgrid.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString() + "' and service='" + form3.ordersgrid.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString() + "'

Comment: Александр посмотрите так получилось я изменил код

Answer (score 0):

У тебя составной первичный ключ видимо из Id заказа и количества
уже существует запись на заказ 23 с количеством 1, вот он и не может тебе сделать такой же

измени первичный ключ

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Completed_orders
  DROP PRIMARY KEY;

ALTER TABLE dbo.Completed_orders
   ADD ID INT IDENTITY
       CONSTRAINT PK_YourTable PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
```

Comment: понимаете мне препод так сказал сделать я ему говорил а он не в какую делай как я сказала

Comment: Там связь многие ко многим между таблицами `Orders` и `Service`. А вы предлагаете сломать её.

Comment: Связь нужно оставить, добавив еще 1 поле order_id как внешний ключь(погугли как это сделать)

Comment: я знаю как внешние ключи добавлять

Comment: ну если знаешь, то сделай

Comment: Не нужно ничего менять в схеме таблицы. Уже имеются все необходимые ключи.

Comment: Alexander код то работает но ничего не редактируется